# C++ Netbeans debugging issues

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, gdb, msys

I installed netbeans6.7.1 ide for c/c++ also i have mingw/msys cygwin installed and i have given C:\Msys\bin as environment variable path.It has gdb7 version.However wheni run dbugging thru netbeans it prompts that GDB version 0 not supported on this platform.Pls help
I have made the project from existing files by giving netbeans the path of makefile.
Also pls provide some tips on debugging in netbeans using gdb.

Answer (score 1):

read and follow [the doc](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/cpp-setup-instructions.html). [it says](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/cpp-setup-instructions.html#mingw) that for netbeans 6.7.x with mingw you need [gdb 6.8](http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=2435&filename=gdb-6.8-mingw-3.tar.bz2&a=66334146).